# Passing a value to a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have some HTML anchor elements and I would like to set a handler for each of them.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // I select all of the anchors
    var myAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");

    // I iterate through the anchors and set a handler to each of them
    for (var i = 0; i < myAnchors.length; i++) {
        myAnchors[i].onclick = handleControl;
    }
}

function handleControl(e) {
    var id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
}
```

I'm unable to understand how setting an handler passes an argument to the `handleControl` function. In other words, how does `myAnchors[i].onclick = handleControl;` pass a value `e` to the handler?

I got this code from a JavaScript programming book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't. Basically you're saying what function should be *used* when, at some point in time, a value becomes available. So for example, there you're saying that when the link is clicked, the function you specified, `handleControl`, should be called. The parameter `e` is passed to it by the browser, which represents information about the click event.

So think of it like:

1. browser detects a click on the link
2. it creates an "event object" that contains information about the event
3. it invokes the handler function you specified with the "event object" as an argument. You can imagine it does something like `anchor.onclick(event_info)`, where `event_info` corresponds to the `e` parameter you have on `handleControl`.

Keep in mind, this isn't necessarily *exactly* what's happening, but the point to answer your question is that the parameter comes from elsewhere (in this case, the browser), and is passed to an invocation of the function you specify.

Comment: Finally someone that read the actual question.  Was just digging through the spec to see if I could find the point that actually specifies this behaviour, but not found it yet... Suspect it's buried in [this bit](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/) somewhere...

Comment: @JamesThorpe Maybe this one? [`interface EventListener { void handleEvent(in Event evt); };`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener)

Comment: @Andreas I was more looking for the bit that defines the creation of the `Event` object itself before calling the handler, but I stopped looking a while ago :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want to know the how?

In layman terms:

1. hi, im an element, and you can click on me
2. Ok, when I click on you I want the function `handleControl` to be executed, here you got a reference to that function.
3. Thank you
4. *User clicks*
5. Oh boy! I'm clicked, let see if i got a function reference on my `onclick` attribute
6. Yes.. yes i do! Okay, let me fire this function and give some event information while doing this
7. Calling `this.onclick(e);` with `e` being an `Event` object, and `this.onclick` the reference to the handler function

If this is not what you asked for, i feel stupid and you can ignore this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how setting an handler passes an argument to the handleControl function. In other words, how does `myAnchors[i].onclick = handleControl;` pass a value `e` to the handler?

So, `onClick` event will trigger one function:

```
function(e) {
   // Whatever you want to do with clicked 'anchor' e, do it here
}
```

Internally you will get the clicked anchor object as `e` here.

In your example the function

```
function handleControl(e) {
    var id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
}
```

does the same.

Answer (score 0):

So when you do

```
   myAnchors[i].onclick = handleControl;
```

You are actually registering a callback function to 
       myAnchors[i] element's click event. 

The dom engine of the browser keeps track of all the callbacks for each event for each dom element.
Now when an event occurs for element, then dom engine calls all the callbacks corresponding to the element and that event. But it calls with a parameter which is event object.

Answer (score 0):

Here the function `handleControl` is subscribed to the DOM Element.

 So if any click event triggers from DOM, the Event Info e will get passed to the subscribed method.